# ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4044) while connecting through Python Code

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, self-signed-certificate

I have received x509 certificate (certificate.pem file) containing Private Key and Certificate in same file. I am trying to establish the connection using Python code through SSL but unfortunately getting below error :

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4044)
```

Python version I am using  : 3.9.13
Open SSL Python has : 1.1

```
Certificate.pem entry :

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
<...............\>
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<..........\>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have reviewed the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain and not sure if Encrypted Private key has anything to do with this error.

Below is the code snippet I am using and it is throwing an error at line context.load_cert_chain

```
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certificate_path)
        # Make a GET request to the API
        headers = {
            'User-ID': user_id,
            'API-Key': api_key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=certificate_path)
```

I have verified the software versions, Key and certificate, path and permission of certificate file, reviewed the _ssl.c file at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_ssl.c
but could not able to understand the actual issue here.

I have already gone through many similar questions posted on this as well as on other portal but nothing is much help and therefore it would be very helpful if any help is granted on this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Without the password an encrypted key obviously cannot be loaded. load_cert_chain has an explicit argument to provide the password for the encrypted key. Use it.

Comment: *" I actually got this through the documentation and below is mentioned "* - I don't understand this sentence. As for the documentation you have linked in your question - it explicitly mentions the password argument.

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich for your valuable response. I actually got this through the documentation [https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain] but I understood it as if private key is encrypted as well as password protected (there could be a possibility that private key is encrypted but no password is needed). Have I got it wrong and actually no matter what if Private key is encrypted we must use password to decrypt? Please advice and accordingly I asked provider to share the password as well. Little hesitant to reach out to them with half info. Thank you!

Comment: If a private key is encrypted then it is always encrypted with a password, i.e. there is not *"encrypted __as well__ as password protected"* but it is *"encrypted __with__ the password"*. This means you need to use the password to actually use the private key.

Comment: It is not fully clear though what you are trying to achieve in the first place. Right now you are trying to use the certificate both as a client certificate within mutual TLS (using `load_cert_chain`) but also as a CA certificate to validate the server certificate (using `verify` argument). This makes not much sense. If this is only to validate the server certificate then you should not use `load_cert_chain` and they should not have provided you with the private key in the first place. If you should use this as a client certificate then you need the password for the private key.

Comment: I am newbie with SSL and this is the first time I am working with X509 certificate. Actually we need to connect to third party source system to retrieve the data through API call and this API call needs to be authenticated using user_id, API Key and x509 certificate. Initially they asked us to provide the x509 certificate but due to some challenge we could not able to therefore they suggested other way round where they shared the x509 certificate (including Private key) and asked us to intimate the connection using this certificate.

Comment: Having said that, I might be wrong about client or server term ology but at the end I need to make a connection using this certificate to their system. Hope it helps you to give some background about the use case. Thank you for helping so far.

Comment: Also I believe your investigation is spot on about the password. I was looking at the wrong _ssl.c file. When I checked the one for my Python version code near line 4044 it does pointing out about the password. Please check at link [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.13/Modules/_ssl.c] near line 4044.

Comment: So the approach with `load_cert_chain` is correct for the client certificates, only that you also need to provide the password. As for the `verify` parameter - this is then likely wrong since this would expect that the server authenticates with your certificate. Unless the specifically provided a CA certificate for you just leave this option unset so that it verifies using publicly trusted CA.